# Unable to install elementR

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the package elementR, an older package that is no longer maintained. I've tried numerous approaches and am still unable to install it.

The first method I tried was to install it from github using:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("charlottesirot/elementR", force = TRUE)
library(elementR)
runElementR()
```

which produced this error:

> ```
> Error: object 'read.ods' is not exported by 'namespace:readODS'
> Execution halted
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'elementR'
> * removing 'C:/Users/alanb/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/elementR'
> Warning messages:
> 1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
>   problem copying C:\Users\alanb\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\00LOCK\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll to C:\Users\alanb\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll: Permission denied
> 2: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
>   problem copying C:\Users\alanb\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\00LOCK\curl\libs\x64\curl.dll to C:\Users\alanb\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\curl\libs\x64\curl.dll: Permission denied
> 3: In i.p(...) :
>   installation of package ‘C:/Users/alanb/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCk4w9S/file248391616b7/elementR_1.3.7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> ```

I have also tried downloading the tar.gz file and downloading it manual, downloading the package with Rtools installed, and downloading it under an older version of R. All to no effect. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: That package seems to use the `readODS` pacakge but it's trying to import functions that have since been removed ( `read.ods`, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readODS/news/news.html). You will need to install an old version or `readODS` as well in order to get things to work.

Comment: You don't seem to have admin in order to write results on install, the 'permission denied' part.

Comment: @Chris You **should not** run package installations as an admin user (if you’re doing this stop it immediately and fix your R configuration — unless, of course, you’re actually managing a multi-user installation). And if you look at the paths in the message you see that they are all in the user folder so they shouldn’t require elevated privileges. Something else is going wrong.